# AMD CodeAnalyst Missing System Data Tab

Tags: code-analysis, code-analyst

Hi I just downloaded the AMD CodeAnalyst 3.8.1203.1066 and while going through the Demo it states that after a profiling is done for hotspots a system data tab would appear however I cannot see this tab any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Start a time based profiling after clicking start (Green button).click on session in the left panel. In Session.tbp window the leftmost tab is System Data.